# Como abrir un repositorio de github a android studio y crear el .apk?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, app, apk, build

El repositorio es este https://github.com/danielmonleonguerrero/SmartBlood_APP

Me descargue la carpeta del proyecto de ese repositorio y la abri en android studio pero cuando quiero crear un .apk solo me aparece la opcion de crear el apk para subirla directamente a playstore, y no quiero eso solamente quiero el apk para probarlo en mi celular, alguien me puede ayudar? es para mi secundaria, muchas gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la imagen se muestra que tu proyecto no está configurado como un proyecto para Android Studio, debes recordar que **en ocasiones tarda un poco en tratar de sincronizar el proyecto con los archivos Gradle,** por lo que tienes que esperar un poco.

Te sugiero descargar el proyecto desde GitHub e importarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

selecciona tu proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no inicia la sincronización de los archivos gradle con tu proyecto, ve a la opción "Run" y trata de iniciar tu proyecto o editar la configuración para que se dispare la sincronización.